# How to get Spacy to tokenize am/pm expressions correctly?

Tags: python, spacy

Spacy seems unable to correctly tokenize am/pm expressions where the number and the am/pm part is not separated by whitespace.

Example: "Something happened at 9am" produces an unexpected token set:
List of Token objects: [Something, happened, at, LIKE_URL, am]

While "Something happened at 9 am" works just fine:
List of Token objects: [Something, happened, at, 9, am]

To reproduce:

```
    >>> import spacy
    >>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
    >>> doc = nlp(u"Something happened at 9am")
    >>> tokens = [x for x in doc]
    >>> tokens
    [Something, happened, at, LIKE_URL, am]

    >>> doc2 = nlp("Something happened at 9 am")
    >>> tokens2 = [x for x in doc]
    >>> tokens2
    [Something, happened, at, 9, am]
```

I notice that if you drill down into the Token object, the 'orth' representation of the token is a 9. Likewise, if I try '8am', the token reads 'IS_UPPER' and the 'orth' representation of the token is 8.

In particular this is a problem for me because I need to track token spans accross a wider context, and a token that shows up as "8" in the text but "IS_UPPER" in token form causes my spans to be off by 7. (IE the actual document-level index (token.idx) of the next token is off by 7)

How can I process a document with spacy that contains am/pm expressions sometimes denoted in the format described above, and retrieve accurate token spans?

I'm using Python 2.7.12 with Spacy 1.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, this was reported as a bug about a month ago:
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/736

Upgrading to Spacy 1.6.0 resolves the issue.